# Highcharts: Getting average values for selection in line graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, average

In a line common chart: http://jsfiddle.net/yuKwp/

How can I get the average value of xAxis on selected elements?

In the above example, I can only access to the min and max values of the graph but not the inbetweeen values nor the minimum point selected value.

So, if I have 1,2,3,4,5 and I select points from 2 to 4 I want to have an array with [2,3,4] with an average value of (2+3+4)/3.

Is there any way to get, at least, the index array of min and max xAxis values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to count average value of points that will be in plot after xAxis extremes will be set, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuKwp/3/
(i.e. you select points from 2 to 4, but after setting extremes, in plot will be points from 1 to 5)

But if you want to only count point that selected by yourself, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuKwp/4/

Hope this helps, but if not, don't be afraid to ask me.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. This was exactly what I was looking for. Where is the documentation about this? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: afterSetExtremes event is not documented, I found it in the source code. My job is directly related to Highcharts library, so I think that I know it almost completely.